# How to Get Hyperledger Indy Running on Ubuntu 16.04 or Windows or PlayWithDocker

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

Other than the example/demo from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llwfb5Ut5sg&t=2823s => https://github.com/swcurran/education/tree/master/LFS171x/indy-material/nodejs

I can not seem to get Hyperledger Indy (SDK or Node) succefully up and running from any of the guides:
- https://indy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ OR 
-https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk OR 
-https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node#about-indy-node OR -Any guide on Medium.com or a google search.

On either my Ubuntu 16.04 OS, my Windows OS or Play With Docker online.

A common error is that the "libindy dependancy is not found" - but https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk#installing-the-sdk always fails as well.

Has anyone recently and successfully done so? Any tips to get started developing would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to get a local Indy network , please try
**[von-network](https://github.com/bcgov/von-network)**